# How do I access Fauxton on the Google AppEngine platform?

Tags: google-app-engine, couchdb, fauxton

I am creating an offline-first app on Google App Engine, with PouchDB as my local DB, and CouchDB as my remote DB. I have enabled CouchDB on Google AppEngine, and tried to go to the following URL:

```
https://[my-app-id].appspot.com:5984/_utils/
```

When I do that, I get the following:

```
This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

So I tried enabling `https` access in the firewall settings.

```
**Firewalls**
[ ] Allow HTTP traffic
[Y] Allow HTTPS traffic
```

Still getting the error above.

I searched the documentation but cannot find anything helpful about how to access Fauxton (or Futon) on Google AppEngine. (The instructions only tell you [how to access Fauxton on your local machine](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/infrastructure/couchdb/#how-to-connect-to-fauxton).)

I have [generated a private and public key and logged in to the server via command line](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/#obtaining-your-ssh-credentials-from-the-google-cloud-launcher).

I have also followed the [instructions about configuring the firewall to allow remote access](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/#how-to-open-the-server-ports-for-remote-access), and have given it to my PC only.

None of this has enabled me to access `https://[my-app-id].appspot.com:5984/_utils/`

**How do I access Fauxton on the Google AppEngine platform?**

---

**Update**: according to the development tools in my browser, my PouchDB application has successfully created a database to sync to, but it isn't on the server:

[image: screenshot of IndexedDB in Application tab]

**app.yaml file**

```
application: [app-name]
version: 4
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:

- url: /
  script: main.py

- url: /(favicon)\.ico$
  static_files: \1.ico
  upload: /(favicon)\.ico
  application_readable: true

- url: /(package)\.json$
  static_files: \1.json
  upload: /(package)\.json
  application_readable: true

  # Serve images as static resources #
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg|json|ico))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg|json|ico)$
  application_readable: true


- url: /index.html
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html 

- url: /licence.html
  static_files: licence.html
  upload: licence.html 

- url: /privacy.html
  static_files: privacy.html
  upload: privacy.html 

- url: /pouchnotes.manifest
  static_files: pouchnotes.manifest
  upload: pouchnotes.manifest  

- url: /manifest.json
  static_files: manifest.json
  upload: manifest.json

  # static directories #

- url: /img
  static_dir: img

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /css
  static_dir: css


libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

**EDIT**: [I posted this question in the Bitnami community forum](https://community.bitnami.com/t/how-do-i-access-fauxton-on-the-google-appengine-platform/53478) (they provide CouchDB on Google App Engine)

Comment: I also tried putting the remote IP address followed by `:5984/_utils/` but still no luck :(

Comment: I presume this is a flexible environment app, is this correct?

Comment: not sure what is meant by that, sorry

Comment: it's a progressive web app using CouchDB. I also added CORS, PouchDB sync, Google API authentication. CouchDB is enabled on the server.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments

Comment: thanks - I didn't explicitly enable it to be a flexible environment - could that be the problem?

Comment: Please add you `app.yaml` file to the post.

Comment: added it above, thanks (I did wonder if it should have the URL `:5984/utils` in it somewhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting some [help with this from the Bitnami Community Forum](https://community.bitnami.com/t/how-do-i-access-fauxton-on-the-google-appengine-platform/53478/5).

**Answers so far...**

(1) [set up the firewall rules](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/#how-to-open-the-server-ports-for-remote-access) - make sure you have a [permanent IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) for this.

(2) set up [SSH keys to access the server via command line](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/#obtaining-your-ssh-credentials-from-the-google-cloud-launcher)

(3) `sudo /opt/bitnami/couchdb/scripts/ctl.sh stop couchdb`

(4) [edit `local.ini` to point to `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/infrastructure/couchdb/#how-to-connect-to-couchdb-from-a-different-machine) - but note that you will need to type `cd  /opt/bitnami/couchdb/etc/`, press enter, and then `sudo vi local.ini` (rather than `vi local.ini` as the instructions suggest).

(5) [Log in to the external IP address](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/infrastructure/couchdb/#how-to-connect-to-fauxton). (Log in as `admin` and prefix commands with `sudo`)

(NB: you don't need to run this in the GAE flexible environment)

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, one of the references in your post points to Google Compute Engine (GCE), which is an IaaS, not a PaaS like Google App Engine (GAE), you *might* be looking at the wrong product.

The `app.yaml` file indicates you are using the standard environment, which doesn't offer ways to configure a listening port. And it also doesn't allow listening sockets. From [Limitations and restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/sockets/#limitations_and_restrictions_if_lang_is_java_java_7_runtime_only_endif):

> Although App Engine supports sockets, there are certain limitations
>   and behaviors you need to be aware of when using sockets :
>
> - You cannot create a listen socket; you can only create outbound sockets.

The GAE flexible environment *might* be an alternative as it drops many of the standard environment restrictions, but it's a [significantly different](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/flexible-for-standard-users) solution (which I didn't use yet). The remainder of the answer assumes the flexible environment and it's based solely on the documentation.

Not 100% certain, but you *might* need to teach your app to listen to port 8080 instead. From [Listen to port 8080](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#listen_to_port_8080):

> The App Engine front end will route incoming requests to the
>   appropriate module on port 8080. You must be sure that your
>   application code is listening on 8080.

Unless you can use the `forwarded ports` network config (again, not 100% certain, I didn't use flex env). From [Port forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#port_forwarding):

> Port forwarding allows for direct connections to the Docker container
>   on your instances. This traffic can travel over any protocol. Port
>   forwarding is intended to help with situations where you might need to
>   attach a debugger or profiler.
>
> By default, incoming traffic from outside your network is not allowed
>   through the [Google Cloud Platform firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networks-and-firewalls#firewalls). After you have
>   specified port forwarding in your `app.yaml` file, you must add a
>   firewall rule that allows traffic from the ports you want opened.
>
> You can specify a firewall rule in the Networking Firewall Rules page
>   in the [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls) or [using `gcloud`
>   commands](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/using-firewalls).
>
> For example, if you want to forward TCP traffic from port `2222`:
>
> 1. Modify the `app.yaml` to include:
>
>    ```
>    entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT -b :2222 main:app
>    ```
> 2. In the network settings of your `app.yaml`, include:
>
>    ```
>    network:
>      forwarded_ports:
>       - 2222/tcp
>    ```
> 3. Specify a firewall rule in the [Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls) or using [`gcloud compute firewall-rules create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/create) to allow traffic from any
>      source (`0.0.0.0/0`) and from `tcp:2222`.

Comment: thanks! that was definitely an improvement, as the sync tried and failed to get the database (because I have the wrong database name in my script)

Comment: I don't currently have the Docker container enabled - should I have done that?

Comment: also, I am not using the flex env, I discovered, as you have to specify it in `app.yaml`, but I have specified python27 there. I will try changing it

Comment: just changing it to `env: flex` to see what happens :)
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml

Comment: nope, darn, got the following error message. `GET https://[my-app-id].appspot.com:8080/couchdb-1/ net::ERR_FAILED`

Comment: Flex env is a different beast. But you may have to use it, standard env doesn't offer ways to configure the listening port and doesn't allow listening sockets.

Comment: `Error 400: --- begin server output ---
appcfg does not support deploying to the Flexible environment. Use "gcloud app deploy" to deploy "env: flex" apps.
--- end server output ---
`

Comment: thanks for all your help, will try the flexible environment then

Comment: OK so I deployed the flexible environment and got `502 Bad Gateway`

Comment: A common error, may have many reasons. Plenty of discussions on stackoverflow and on the google groups, just google '502 bad gateway app engine'